# Getting image error box on png in internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have this really weird issue with Internet Explorer. I am pre-loading some images with javascript and displaying them. They all display fine, however there is an image error box showing up.

Image here https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkO4y.png

I preload the images this way in Javascript

```
function LoadImage(imageName,imageFile)
{
 if(!document.images) return;
 document.images[imageName].src = imageFile;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
LoadImage('image0','images/image.png');
});
```

And then I use them here in html

```
<img name=image0 border=0>
```

Again, all of the images are showing up fine. This error appears in all versions of IE.

Thanks

Comment: you should access elements via `document.getElementById`, not `document.images`

Answer (score 0):

Is it just one particular .png that is doing that in IE? You might want to open the image in a photo editor like Photoshop to make sure it's RGB, 72dpi, etc. I had a similar issue a while back when a client was supplying me with CMYK JPEGs, and the only browser that wouldn't display them was IE. Converting the colorspace to RGB did the trick.

The easiest way to make sure the image will display in all browsers is probably Photoshop's Save For Web feature.